# sql syntanx error i want to compare two table data in one query

Tags: mysql, database

i want to compare two table data and i write this query please help me to find the error that what is wrong in this query. please correct me where i am wrong here below i write my query

```
SELECT 
   er.roomcleaning,
   er.carwash,
   er.laundry,
   ee.roomcleaning,
   ee.carwash,
   ee.laundry 
FROM  
   Employer_Work AS er , 
   EmployeeRegister AS ee 
WHERE 
   er.roomcleaning=ee.roomcleaning,
   er.carwash=ee.carwash,er.laundry=ee.laundry
```

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT 
   er.roomcleaning,
   er.carwash,
   er.laundry,
   ee.roomcleaning,
   ee.carwash,
   ee.laundry 
FROM  Employer_Work AS er 
    , EmployeeRegister AS ee 
WHERE 
   er.roomcleaning=ee.roomcleaning,
   er.carwash=ee.carwash,
   er.laundry=ee.laundry 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'er.carwash=ee.carwash,er.laundry=ee.laundry LIMIT 0, 25' at line
>   1

please help me i dont know what is wrong in it

Comment: Change the commas in your `WHERE` to `AND`

Comment: WHERE-conditions are not supposed to be separated with a `,` but with `AND` or `OR`

Comment: Do not add erroneous or conflicting flags to your post.

Comment: In SQL Comma's separate values in the select and possibly the from but only if you still live in 1994.  every where else and, or, or on should really be used.  But I understand if you're supporting software from 1994.

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been available for more than 25 years now (longer than MySql has existed). https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    er.roomcleaning,
        er.carwash,
        er.laundry,
        ee.roomcleaning,
        ee.carwash,
        ee.laundry 
FROM    Employer_Work AS er, 
        EmployeeRegister AS ee 
WHERE   er.roomcleaning=ee.roomcleaning
     AND er.carwash=ee.carwash
     AND er.laundry=ee.laundry
```

Comment: its working thank you so much u are a life saviour :) thnks alot